# Vscode - variable expansion in .env file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

Running python tests in VSCode.  I have a `.env` file that **is** loading (I can add new vars, and see the change reflected in a `print(...` of `os.environ`.

However, variable expansion within that file is doing something odd.  It seems to expand `${workspaceFolder}` in some cases (specifically, `PYTHONPATH=`) but **not** others. ??

Here's my `.env` file.  Again, it **is** loading, as I can see changes if i add vars, or change the contents of the (fully working) `PYTHONPATH` var:

```
FOOBAR1=${workspaceFolder}/foobar1.txt
PYTHONPATH=${workspaceFolder}/backend/src:/tmp/foo-2:${env:PYTHONPATH}
```

however `print(`'ing all the `os.environ`'s shows:

```
...
        ?
        v
FOOBAR1=/foobar1.txt
PYTHONPATH=/home/-omitted-/backend/src:/tmp/foo-2:
...
```

`${workspaceFolder}` is expanded for one var, but not the other??  I've tried re-ordering.  Don't see anything here or on google.

Help !?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable expansion in vscode `.env` files at all. Any `${workspaceFolder}` or similar variables are replaced by empty strings.

> Note: Variable substitution is only supported in VS Code settings files, it will not work in .env environment files.
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file

Something else is probably prepending the `/home/-omitted-` to `PYTHONPATH`.